# datetime picker background showing messy

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I create Datetimepicker for Dateofbirth. so i use following jquery code,

**My code is**

```
$("#DOB").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:-16"
});
```

when i execute this one from my local file the result is showing good. in server it is showing messy

Comment: make sure you are loading the proper UI theme CSS..and check your path too

Comment: yes. I check too many times. I added. But why It happend i confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of designing. Perhaps your jQuery UI and CSS file is not included properly on server or you have forgot to upload it. check that is there files of css and jquery UI and also check that there files are found on server.

You can check it by seeing the code of page.